# Powershell switch one to many association

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, powershell-2.0, one-to-many

I am wondering if it is possible to create switch cases with more than 1 value per case. I am trying to take in user input in different ways.
The menu looks something like:

```
    $database = Read-Host "[1] db 1 [2] db2 [3] db3 [4] ALL dbs"
```

This is then passed as a parameter into 4 different functions, based off of what the user response is in my next Read-host.
Without making a ridiculous amount of cases, I want to be able to accept all possible inputs. Ie, if the user wants to see 2 databases, they can enter 32 or 23. If they want to see all, it would accept 4, 321, 123, 213... Currently I am trying to accomplish this by:

```
switch ($database) { 
(4 -or 123 -or 312 -or ...) {#return all paths}
(12 -or 21) { #return 1st 2 db paths}
(31 -or 13) { #return 1st and last db paths}
(1) {#return 1st db path}
...
}
```

This is causing a syntax error, so it clearly does not work. 
As you can tell, there are going to be a lot of cases already (7). If I had to list out every single option there would be more than double (16). Is there a way to create a one to many association in a switch case? If not, does anyone have an idea of a new approach I can take to this problem?

**SOLUTION**

```
    switch -regex ($database)
            {
                "[*1*]" {"\\db1"}
                "[*2*]" {"\\db2"}
                "[*3*]" {"\\db3"} 
                "[4]" {"\\db1";"\\db2";"\\db3"}
                default {Write-Host "Database(s) were not properly specified,
 Please run the script again"
exit}
            }
```

This accomplishes what I was going for, although I was never able to figure out how to put a conditional `-or` in a switch statement, I do not believe it is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you can work on

```
switch -regex ($database)
```

-have a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx)

Comment: `swtich -regex ($dbs) { [123 -or 321] { "\\db1" ;\\db2; "\\db3"; }` produces error : the term 'swtich' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program... I was looking at that page too, but unfortunately this is not a simple "range" like specified in the regular expressions example

Comment: @Cole9350 Convert to a string and use a proper regular expression. e.g. switch -regex ([string]$dbs) { "^123$|^312$" { "\\db1" ;\\db2; "\\db3"; }

Comment: @Cole9350 - Your error message says "`swtich`" - the keyword is `switch` (perhaps you fat-fingered it?).

Comment: haha good call alroc, sorry for the typo I was rushing as it was the end of the workday on a Friday. I will fix this tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `string.Contains`?

```
$result = ""
if ($database.Contains("1") -or $database -eq "4") {
    $result += "db path 1";
}
if ($database.Contains("2") -or $database -eq "4") {
    $result += "db path 2";
}
if ($database.Contains("3") -or $database -eq "4") {
    $result += "db path 3";
}
if ($result = "") {
    #Error condition?
}
return $result
```

Comment: Although this is a great post, I can't say it directly "answered" my question concerning the switch statement. Still, thank you very much, you have provided me with a lot cleaner and nicer code. I actually combined your answer with the switch statement to make it exactly what I was going for

Comment: @Cole9350: I haven't seen the regex syntax before, so couldn't find a good way to combine `Contains` and `-eq`.

Comment: Yea honestly I do not believe this will work in a switch statement because it requires you to call the objects method. I thought I had .contains working with switch -regex but after further testing it was just returning true for every statement. Same thing happens when you put an -and or -or conditional in a switch statment. I ended up going with the switch statement in my post, but looking at it now it probably would have been less of a headache to just use ifs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$database = Read-Host "[1] db 1 [2] db2 [3] db3 [4] ALL dbs"

if($database -like "*4*")
{
    "return all paths"
}
else
{
    [char[]]$database | Select-Object -Unique | Foreach-Object { "return db $_ path" }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great, and I would have implemented it if my actual databases were named db1 db2 and db3. But unfortunately the names of the databases are a bit more random, I just labeled them 1 2 and 3 because I did not want to give away the actual names.

Comment: Your question should reflect your needs, it OK if you can't disclose your db servers name but can always use bogus names. We all try to give the best answer and the original question is all we have.

Comment: Right, sorry for the oversight. It was pretty close to my needs, except db1 db2 and db3 was really just db db2 db3 and the extra if else made it not worth it. I could perhaps use this in the future though so thank you.